Superficial reference on Computer Architecture
If one had to suggest a basic, well-known, comprehensive introductory reference on computer architecture,
it would be reasonable to assume that one would suggest one of the following:

Patterson & Hennessy - Computer Organization and Design
Tanenbaum & Austin - Structured Computer Organization
Stallings - Computer organization and architecture designing for performance
Hamacher, Vranesic, Zaky & Manjikian - Computer Organization and Embedded Systems

These books are all about 1000 pages long.
What you would suggest to someone who wants to get a high-level, initial grasp of the subject without having the time to go over a 1000 page volume? In other words, I am asking who the little brothers of the books above might be.
You can assume the reader to be as mathematically sophisticated as you want but he or she has no idea of computer architecture at all.
And again, as said, he or she can embark on a 200/300 page adventure, 400 tops, but no more than that
(I know it could be deceptive to measure books in pages since it is easier to read 100 easy pages than one single hard one, but you get the point).
Needless to say the potential reader does not
expect to get a knowledge comparable to that of someone who read one of the books I mentioned in the beginning.

(Under the aspect why bother about computer architecture?, I'd look for light shed on bang for buck&Joule.)

if I google bang for buck&Joule i find nothing :|

bang for the buck may be more common; bang for the Joule by analogy.

i am aware of the saying, but i still do not understand what you mean :|

Most computation done for electrical energy consumed - or done sooner for same energy.
